# how to know a cookie is set or not in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I've wrote an array to cakephp Cookie. I could perform read and write operations perfectly. But is there any direct way to know whether some cookie set or not ? . I mean like

```
if($this->Cookie('somevalue')==false) {
 return;
}
```

Comment: you can try if isset($_COOKIE['somevalue']) works.

Comment: @Lake It is the way we can use in normal PHP , I meant in Cakephp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ sudhir
@ newRehtse

since when can use you methods in isset() or empty()?
thats news to me..^^

so correct would be

```
if ($this->Cookie->read('somevalue') !== null) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

In 2.3 they added $this->Cookie->check('key'); you can see it [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html#CookieComponent%3a%3acheck)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read the value and check if it is set, like @Lake told you, but in Cakephp:

```
if ( isset($this->Cookie->read('somevalue') ) ) 
    return;
```

Maybe there is a better way but I didn't find it in the book, [Cookie component](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1282/Using-the-Component)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
$cookieVal = $this->Cookie->read('somename');
//of some specific value in array
$cookieVal = $this->Cookie->read('Somename.somevalue');
if(isset($cookieVal)) {
  echo "Its set";
}
else {
  echo "Not set";
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_null($this->Cookie->read("somevalue")))
{
  //Cookie not set
}
else
{
  //Cookie already set
}
```